# Keychain sharing without paid developer account

Tags: xcode, firebase, macos

I am trying to setup authentication to my Firebase Firestore DB.
I tried both the Google SSO and the email/password authentication types but they both require access to the Keychain (makes sense) with the Keychain Sharing capabilities (not sure I understand what the sharing part gives on top of the normal keychain?)

If I enable Keychain Sharing capabilities I need to provide a provisioning profile. As I do not have any, I need to select the "Automatically manage signing" option in Xcode.

This works fine on my development machine, but when I try to deploy the app to another machine the app does not even start complaining about the profile.

Is there a way to have Keychain support without having a paid account? In the past this was possible.
Otherwise, what are the possibilities here? e.g.

1. Can I allowlist my app on the target machine to not check the profile?
2. Should I create a feature request for Google to make the Keychain sharing optional?